# Objective C instance variable is released despite being retained

Tags: objective-c, retain, instance-variables, null

I have a marshmallow class which has (among other things) a CCSprite object as an instance variable.

here is the init method:

```
-(id) init
{
    if((self = [super init]))
    {   
        model = [[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"marshmallow.png"] retain];
        maxSpeed = 5; //160px per second (maxspeed * PTM_Ratio = px/second max)
        gravity = 9.81; // in meters/sec^2
        health = 3;
    }

    return self;
}
```

the variable is declared in another file as a global variable with the line:

```
Marshmallow *mainChar;
```

Later in the file, it is set (initiated/alloc'd) with this line:

```
mainChar = [[mainChar alloc] init];
```

while writing the previous line, xcode gave me a warning that Marshmallow might not respond to alloc. (I don't think that's related. just mentioning anything that seems wrong)

my problem is that the following line of code returns nil:

```
[mainChar getModel];
```

why does it return nil instead of the instance variable?

here is the getModel function:

```
-(CCSprite *)getModel
{
    return model;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mainChar = [[mainChar alloc] init];
```

Shouldn't be

```
mainChar = [[Marshmallow alloc] init];
```

?

The message says an *object from that class* might not respond to it, not the *class* itself.

Comment: oh....

I feel stupid.

I'm used to programming in java. this is actually my first objective-c program. I didn't realize alloc was a class method. thanks for pointing that out. (bad pun.... pointing)

Comment: No worries @Jacob Sharf, and if it solved the problem don't forget to click on the checkmark below the vote count to accept the answer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in the initialization of your `mainChar` variable. The line you're looking for is this:

```
mainChar = [[mainChar alloc] init];
```

The warning you got is telling you that instances of type `Marshmallow` will not respond to the `-alloc` message. That is your problem: you want to call the `+alloc` class method instead, like so:

```
mainChar = [[Marshmallow alloc] init];
```

Comment: Whoops, didn't notice that there were already answers! Nevermind! :P

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do

```
mainChar = [[MarshMallow alloc] init];
```

instead of

```
mainChar = [[mainChar alloc] init];
```

The error message you got is very important.

Comment: I was still writing (and got interrupted) when you had already posted. <g>